# MySQL de XAMPP se detine de manera inesperada

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Hola les cuento mi problema ayer funcionaba correctamente el MySQL pero hoy al iniciar se detiene de manera inesperada los otros módulos funcionan correctamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el log de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudieran orienta lo agradecería

Comment: Tiene pinta que el cortafuegos de Windows te está jugando una de las suyas. Prueba a abrir el XAMPP Control Panel como Administrador y dale el check de la izquierda para instarlo como servicio. Eso debería forzar al cortafuegos a que lo acepte.

Comment: La otra prueba es desactivar temporalmente el cortafuegos de Windows y probar a subirlo de nuevo.

Comment: ve el firewall o simplemente desinstala xampp y vuelve lo a instalar

Comment: @phpMyGuel lo instale como administrador y lo ejecute como administrador y no funciono

Comment: @Alfabravo lo he desactivado y no funciona :c

Comment: Ya desactive el firewall y lo instale 2 veces

Comment: Otro de los problemas que suelen ser recurrentes es que exista otro programa que esté usando el mismo puerto que usa **MySQL** (por defecto el 3306) Si ayer te funcionaba correctamente y no hoy es posible que un nuevo programa que hayas instalado te esté ocasionando esta colisión. ¿Has instalado algún programa en tu sistema entre ayer y hoy?

Comment: No, de hecho chece con el netstat para ver si alguna aplicación lo esta ocupando y no estaba ocupado el puerto 3306

Comment: prueba con esta solucion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly me paso lo mismo alguna vez y me funciono

Comment: Pues lo desinstale otras 3 veces y ya parece estable pero espero que mañana siga funcionando